# Ошибка при написании интерфейса(я новичок)

Tags: java, интерфейс

Недавно начал изучать Java, и в ходе обучения пришел к такой теме как "Интерфейсы", я писал задачку и возникла ошибка.

```
class Square {
    int border_radius = 0;
    char procent = '%';
}

interface Square {
    void changeBorder(int border_rad);
}

class Circle {
    int ugol = 3;
    char names = 'a';
}

interface Circle {
     public void changeNames(int name);
}

class docsoracle implements Circle{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square square = new Square();
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        int anchor, x, c;

        void changeNames(int names) {
        anchor = names;
   }
    // comment
   System.out.println("is working");
   }
```

}

в консоли выдается такое:

```
docs.oracle.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
    void changeNames(int names) {
    ^
docs.oracle.java:20: error: ';' expected
    void changeNames(int names) {
                    ^
docs.oracle.java:20: error: ';' expected
    void changeNames(int names) {
                              ^
3 errors
```

P.S. Я не думаю, что это важно, но на всякий случай скину задачку
*1.Создайте новые классы для каждого объекта реального мира, который вы наблюдали в начале этого следа. Обратитесь к классу Bicycle, если вы забыли требуемый синтаксис.
2.Для каждого нового класса, который вы создали выше, создайте интерфейс, который определяет его поведение, а затем потребуйте, чтобы ваш класс его реализовал.*

Comment: С таким знанием синтаксиса Вы ничего не напишите. interface Circle {
    public void setUgo(int ugo);
    public void setName(char name); class CircleImpl implements Circle{
    
    int ugo;
    char name;
    public void setUgo(int ugo) {
        this.ugo = ugo;
    }

  
    public void setName(char name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
} Это пример реализации интерфейса одним классом, дальше сами. И не сдавайтесь так быстро, иначе джаву вам не выучить

Comment: в `main` по определению не может быть никаких функций

Comment: и вы перекаверкали использование интрефейса как только можно

Comment: Прежде чем изучать интерфейсы, изучите как следует структуру классов и синтаксис описания методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь творится полная каша. 
Во первых нету ни одного `public` класса. Во вторых, вы всередине метода `main` начинаете объявлять новый метод `changeNames`, в котором хотите присвоить значение переменной, которая вне зоны видимости этого метода при том, что вы вообще не можете описывать какие-то новые функции в середине `main`. В третьих, даже если и так, как минимум там не хватает одной `}`. 
Я понимаю, вы хотите изменить значения `anchor`, на то, какое будет передано как аргумент метода `changeNames`, но вы не сможете этого сделать, так как измененное значение будет существовать только в скоупе этого метода и для этого вам надо хотя бы вернуть это значение из метода. Следующее, не может быть два типа данных с одним именем. К примеру, класс и интерфейс.
Немного исправил ваш код, возможно наведет на какие-то правильные мысли, но в вашем примере очень много ошибок. Стоит сначала разобраться что такое класс и методы класса, какие есть зоны видимости у переменных и как вообще можно и не можно объявлять переменные и новые методы.

```
interface Circle {
int changeNames(int name);
}

class Docsoracle implements Circle
{
public int changeNames(int name)
{
    return name;
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle circle = new Docsoracle();
    int anchor = circle.changeNames(5);
    System.out.println(anchor);
}
}
```

Кроме всего этого, методы интерфейсов по умолчанию `public`.